# React + Firestore reading data infinite results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get all documents from a collection in Firestore using React JS. Originally I had this code which is directly from the Firebase documentation:

```js
db.collection("articles").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
  });
```

When I log this in the console, it prints each document twice.
Also, when I change the code to this:

```js
const [headlines, setHeadlines] = useState([])
  db.collection("articles").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        setHeadlines(prevHeadlines => [...prevHeadlines, doc.data().article1])
    });
  });
```

When I log the length of the array headlines, it seems to be infinitely increasing, it does not stop and keeps going. There are only 14 documents in the database so there is no way there should be that many elements in the array.
I am new to React JS and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is this code, particularly the  `db.collection()` section?

If it is NOT in a `useEffect()` hook, it will be run EVERY TIME THE COMPONENT RENDERS.  Since it changes state (`setHeadlines`), it will change state every time the `db.collection()...` runs; every time it changes state it will be re-rendered, so ...

Since you wrote it as `` setHeadlines(`prevHeadlines => [...prevHeadlines, doc.data().article1]) `` it will add the `collection().get()` onto the previous headlines everytime, forever.